# Java class to replace print statement and scanner input

Tags: java

Good Evening All,

I need help writing a class that enables to write a code like:

```
int number  = Utility.getInt("Enter an int", '>');
```

to replace something like:

```
System.out.println("Enter an int>");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(system.in);
int number = scan.nextInt();
```

Please find my solution below. I am not sure if I am understanding the prompt correctly, not sure if I need to use a Java pre-defined Utility class or if I just need to name the class Utility. Any help or tip would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```
public class Utility {
private int number; 
public Auto setInt (int number){
return "Enter an int" + number;
if (number>0)
   this.number = newNumber;
return this;
}
public int getInt(){
return newNumber;
}
}
```

Comment: According to the code you posted, method `setInt()`, in class `Utility`, returns `Auto`. I am unfamiliar with `Auto`. Is it part of JDK? Is it a class that you wrote?

Comment: The code you posted for class `Utility` does not compile.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried static methods like below ?

```
public class Utility {
    public static Integer getInt(String message){
        System.out.println(message);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Integer number = scan.nextInt();
        return number;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest passing the Scanner object into the method, so that if it is not `System.in` then it can be closed by the calling process.